# how to delay in ajax succes of 2 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i fetch data from each loop so i get response very fast i need delay i tried every thing(setTimeout),delay but no benefite. i think there is diffrent approach i should use but i dont know how. please any help thanks. here is my code:

```
    var counter = 0;
    var dataLength = 0;

    function processEachRow(data) {
     $("#LoadingImage").show();
     var result =
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/assessment/omr-evaluation/post-omr-skill-based-career-test.aspx',
             data: { row: data },
             async: false,

             success:
             function (data) {
                 counter = counter + 1;
                 if (counter < dataLength) {
                   $("#LoadingImage").show();
                 }
                 var arr = new Array();
                 var names = data;
                 arr = names.split('^');
                 //alert(arr);
                 //console.log(arr);
                 var userTable = $('#user_table_id');
                 if (userTable == null || userTable.length == 0) {
                     var table_html = "<table id='user_table_id'>";
                     table_html += "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Email</td><td>Phone</td><td>PDf</td></tr>";
                     table_html += "</table>";
                     $('#user_table_id').html(table_html);

                 }
                 newRow = "<tr><td>" + arr[0] + "</td><td>" + arr[1] + "     </td><td>" + arr[2] + "</td><td>" + arr[3] + "</td></tr>";
                 userTable.append(newRow);
                 $("#LoadingImage").hide();


             },
                    error: function (result) {
                    $("#LoadingImage").hide();
                    alert("Failed From Timeout");
                },

            })


        return result;
    }

    function processFiles() {
        d3.csv(("/assessment/omr-evaluation/uploaded-csv/" + $('#Label2').text()), function (data) {
            var dataLength = data.length;
            //alert(dataLength);
            $.each(data, function (i) {
                //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data[i]);
                var result = '';
                result = processEachRow(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
                //alert(i + result);

            });


        })
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Don't make the AJAX calls in a loop. Have the `success` function of one call start the next one.

Comment: @barmer looping is neccesary

Comment: I generally prefer not to repeatedly hit the server at all. If you control the backend, you could construct a single payload containing an array of data instead of one request per row.

Comment: so now what shoould be the approach i dont want to change flow of code i am just stuck

Comment: Is the order of you requests and responses important?

Comment: When you declare a variable inside a function with `var` (`var dataLength`) you create a local variable and DO NOT modify the one you declared on the beginning, which I guess you wanted to be a global.

Comment: not too much important. we can change the way but i dont have any idea of another aproach . may be it should be recursive calling but i dont know how to do this @ikken

Comment: @dheerajsharma Looping can be converted to recursion.

Comment: What about adding delay in your server ajax call? Not very elegant but might solve your problem.. Another possibility, much more elegant, is to accumulate all data you need and send only ONE ajax call.

Comment: i tried it but no luck

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve by adding the delay? From a high-level view. Is it that it's freezing the UI thread?

Comment: yes@mic i want each responsed data come with delay

Comment: Is there a possibility to utilize Promises? That way you can perform your logic after all have resolved.

Comment: Or do most of the work in a debounced function called from the callback, so you only add the rows to the DOM when there's a break in the responses from the server. That way you can also do a big-bang DOM update instead of one per row.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to delay ajax success like this:

```
// set your delay here, 2 seconds as an example...
var my_delay = 2000;

// call your ajax function when the document is ready...
$(function() {
    callAjax();
});

// function that processes your ajax calls...
function callAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        // ajax parameters here...
        // ...
        success: function() {
            setTimeout(callAjax, my_delay);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried this but no luck. its problem of loop whoch i used

Answer (score 0):

I had to mock out a lot of parts of it, but I put together an example with the success callback using a debounced function, which is provided by Ben Alman's jquery plugin - found here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

It's worth noting that without the plugin you could fairly easily write a debounce function with a setTimeout and a callback and cancel. You would also find one in many of the popular functional-style libraries like Underscore or Lodash.

I've put in quite a few comments to try to explain it, but in brief: my successCb function would by your success function from your jquery ajax call (I mocked that since I have no server to post to). All it does is add its data to an array for processing and call the addRowsToTable function. Since the addRowsToTable function is debounced, it only actually executes when the calls to it have stopped for a number of milliseconds (150 in my example). In this case, since my fake response times are 20ms, it will execute only one time, after all the data comes back. Finally, since DOM updates can get expensive, I made it update for all available rows one time outside the loop instead of appending in a loop.

The rest is pretty much all mocking stuff you already have.

```js
var rows = [];
var pendingRequests = 0;

//these are just for display purposes.
var addRowsCalls = 0;
var addRowsSpan = $('#addRowsCalls');
var successCbCalls = 0;
var successCbSpan = $('#successCbCalls');

function mockAjax(responsePayload, callback, delay) {
  //Using this instead of jquery ajax call because I don't have your server-side endpoint.
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(responsePayload)
  }, delay);
}

/*
the magic of this is in the debounce, which delays the execution of the provided function
until calls to it have stopped by the provided delay period (150ms in this case).
This is provided via this plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
*/
var addRowsToTable = $.debounce(150, function() {
  //these 3 lines should be removed.
  addRowsCalls += 1;
  addRowsSpan.text(addRowsCalls);  
  console.log('addRowsToTable called');
  
  var userTable = $('#user_table_id');
  var table_html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    pendingRequests -= 1;
    var arr = new Array();
    arr = rows[i].split('^');
    table_html += "<tr><td>" + arr[0] + "</td><td>" + arr[1] + "     </td><td>" + arr[2] + "</td><td>" + arr[3] + "</td></tr>";
  }
  userTable.html(userTable.html() + table_html);
  if (pendingRequests === 0)
    $("#LoadingImage").hide();
});


var successCb = function(data) {
  //these 2 lines can go as well.
  successCbCalls += 1;
  successCbSpan.text(successCbCalls);
  
  rows.push(data);
  addRowsToTable();
};

function processEachRow(data) {
  pendingRequests += 1;
  console.log('sent data: [' + data + '] to server');
  mockAjax(data.join('^'), successCb, 20); //20ms to simulate a reasonably fast response from the server but still make it perceptible.
}



function processFiles() {
  //Replacing this function with a mock version to make it testable without external resources.
  var mockData = [
    [1, 'Alpha', 'Blue', 'pdf1'],
    [2, 'Bravo', 'Green', 'pdf2'],
    [3, 'Charlie', 'Red', 'pdf3'],
    [4, 'Delta', 'Yellow', 'pdf4'],
    [5, 'Echo', 'Purple', 'pdf5'],
    [1, 'Alpha', 'Blue', 'pdf1'], //duplicated to inflate data set.
    [2, 'Bravo', 'Green', 'pdf2'],
    [3, 'Charlie', 'Red', 'pdf3'],
    [4, 'Delta', 'Yellow', 'pdf4'],
    [5, 'Echo', 'Purple', 'pdf5'],
    [1, 'Alpha', 'Blue', 'pdf1'],
    [2, 'Bravo', 'Green', 'pdf2'],
    [3, 'Charlie', 'Red', 'pdf3'],
    [4, 'Delta', 'Yellow', 'pdf4'],
    [5, 'Echo', 'Purple', 'pdf5'],
    [1, 'Alpha', 'Blue', 'pdf1'],
    [2, 'Bravo', 'Green', 'pdf2'],
    [3, 'Charlie', 'Red', 'pdf3'],
    [4, 'Delta', 'Yellow', 'pdf4'],
    [5, 'Echo', 'Purple', 'pdf5'],
    [1, 'Alpha', 'Blue', 'pdf1'],
    [2, 'Bravo', 'Green', 'pdf2'],
    [3, 'Charlie', 'Red', 'pdf3'],
    [4, 'Delta', 'Yellow', 'pdf4'],
    [5, 'Echo', 'Purple', 'pdf5'],
  ];
  $('#LoadingImage').show();
  $.each(mockData, function(itemIndex, itemValue) {
    //JSON.stringify the itemValue since that's what your server expects.
    //I'm omitting so that I can use join later to fake to carat delimited structure your success callback expects.
    processEachRow(itemValue);
  });

}

processFiles();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js"></script>
<p>
  Number of times successCb is called: <span id="successCbCalls">0</span>
</p>
<p>
  Number of times addRowsToTable is called: <span id="addRowsCalls">0</span>
</p>
<table id="user_table_id">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>PDf</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="LoadingImage" style="background-color:red; display:none;">
  Loading...
</div>
```